# problem with Pyglet on Bullseye and respberry pi 4: Could not create GL context

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, pyglet, openglcontext, bullseye

I'm trying to use pyglet on Raspberry pi 4 (Bullseye) to create a simple window. But at compile time I get the following error message: **Could not create GL context**.

Here is my simple code:

```
import pyglet 
displays = pyglet.canvas.get_display() 
screens = displays.get_screens()
window = pyglet.window.Window()
```

I have done the following steps to resolve the issue with no luck:

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev

sudo apt install mesa-utils

config.txt already includes:

dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

I have also uninstalled and re-installed pyglet multiple times, done multiple reboots. No luck. Does anyone have a possible solution for this?